# Setting up an application in QT Creator that uses QGIS API

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I am a 15 year veteran of Java making my first entry in to C++ applications.  I have a specific need to develop a desktop application that produces graphics type output as well as displaying embedded maps.  It looks like Qt and QGIS API are exactly what I need to get this going.

I have been playing around with Qt Creator and generated several of the tutorials without too much problems.  Now I am trying my first Qt project that incorporates the QGIS API.  I am really stuck.  I can't figure out where the libraries are that contains the QGIS modules.  I think I have an idea how to configure the Qt project if I could find QGIS.  I found all the .h files but some of what I need just aren't there.

There are some good examples of code that shows how to code with QGIS classes.  But I can't find anything that explains how to set the project up.  Could someone please help guide me through setting up a project in Qt Creator that will allow me to incorporate the QGIS modules?  I have been searching everywhere.  Google can be a strange beast.  Sometimes you find what you need on the first search.  Other times it just never happens.

Answer (score 3):

Check Tim's blog: [Using QtCreator with QGIS](http://linfiniti.com/2011/06/using-qtcreator-with-qgis/) and in QGIS' source you'll find `src/plugins/plugin_builder.py`

Comment: I tried Tim's blog.  The instructions he provides are for Linux.  They don't work for Windows.

Comment: What doesn't work there?  I'd except that the generated cmake stuff for a new plugin works just like the rest of the (core) plugins.  Did you build QGIS with QtCreator on Windows?  Because the usual C++ QGIS libraries don't work with MinGW and require MSVC 2008.

Comment: I have successfully built QGis on windows using VS 2010 Express.  The generated QGis application itself works great.  Now I am trying to integrate the QGis API in a Qt Creator project.  I got the libraries in and get a good compile.  But when I try to run the test ap it fails because it can't find any of the objects in the DLLs.  It appears I need a "xxx.a" file to add to the project so it knows what DLLs to include.  I don't have one in my QGis installation.   How do I create this file?

Comment: AFAIK MinGW and VS C++ ABI are incompatible. You can't use C++ stuff from VS with MinGW.  So either use VS for your plugin or build QGIS with MinGW.

Comment: Thanks.  It's really tough finding this sort of stuff out.  Everyone says do it yourself yet there is no guidance.  The only instructions I have found were for VS.  Everything else is for really much older versions of QGis and do not work with the latest version.  I get to a certain step in the instructions and an identified tool no longer exists or works completely different.

However, I would have thought that once the libs and DLLs were generated it wouldn't matter how they were created.  Otherwise how would windows be able to figure it out?  An executable is an executable, right?

Comment: One thing I just learned is that the archive files (.a) are for Linux, not windows.  Windows builds the pointers to the DLLs in the lib file.  Are you suggesting that MinGW is generating "pseudo Linux" binaries on windows?

Comment: No, .a and .lib follow the same concept.  That isn't a problem unless you want to use the libraries built with one compiler with the other.  IIRC for VC/MinGW it's just a matter of renaming the libraries file. MinGW like any gcc and probably most other unix toolchains expects libfoo.a while VC uses foo.lib.
The C ABI are compatible.  But the issue here is the C++ ABI - and that might also be an issue between different versions of VC++.

Comment: re C++ ABI eg. different implementations of name mangling, handling of virtual methods, exception handling etc.

Comment: After a long arduous journey I'm not sure I'm any closer now than I have been.  It really is a shame to have to spend months just trying to get the tools where they need to be in order just to start using them.  Is it possible someone has a valid and working build of QGis in the Windows environment that enables the use of the API!!  If so would you consider sharing it with the rest of us?

Comment: Either use MSVC 9/2008 with the stuff from osgeo4w (Qt, Python...; See http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html#toc14).   That works even without building QGIS yourself.But anything else is mostly unknown territory, that you need to explore yourself.

Comment: Did you ever find how to do this? The only links I can find are how access the source code of QGIS from Qt in order to develop it not just get a handle on it. This is really odd to me coming from a dev background in Com/.Net where it would be a few lines of code!

Comment: Blog link is dead....

Comment: I think that this links is the same @heikkivesanto https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/qgisdevelopersguide/qtcreator.html and https://gist.github.com/timlinux/a8ae0aed44ccd2e4c7bb