# How can I connect qt ui with qgis, which browse the data file?

Tags: qgis, python, plugins, qt-designer

I have created a form in qt designer which is basically a dialog box with line edit and a browse button to browse .csv files.

I am trying to connect this with QGIS so that as soon as a layer is loaded the dialog box pops up in which we can browse for the attribute file which is in .csv format.

I have written python logic also ,but i am not getting the dialog box asking for the file to browse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up an application in QT Creator that uses QGIS API](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29529/setting-up-an-application-in-qt-creator-that-uses-qgis-api)

Comment: i want to create it using pyqt as a plugin but the link you have posted is totally different